# How did $4\pi\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0/4\pi$ originate in Electrostatics and Magnetism Respectively?

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields

Our school text books simply cite the constants $\frac{1}{4πε_0}$ and $\frac{μ_0}{4π}$ for (electrostatics and magnetism respectively) with mentioning how they're derived.

[Though somewhere along the way we were told that Cavendish came up with the constants for the universal gravitation equation as well as for the equation for electrostatic force between two point charges, but that wasn't exactly very helpful...]

So would anyone here be able to tell me how those constants came into being?

Comment: The 4$\pi$ got in there because "it would be better, in situations of spherical geometry, to include a factor 4π in equations like Coulomb's law,..."- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity#Historical_origin_of_the_parameter_.CE.B50. The numerical values of $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ are strongly realated to the CGS and later SI unit system.

Comment: Someone gave a great answer to this recently, but of course I can't find it.  Maybe someone else can find it?